# PostgreSQL Stored Procedure error in declare bloc

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm trying to convert a T-SQL procedure to PL/PGSQL, in my procedure a have a declared variable used in a cursor. But when i execute the procedure i have an error: "unknown variable"
find below the code and th error message

```
create or replace function public.UP_GetCumulPerformancesParPortefeuille(strMatricule VARCHAR(20), strDevise varchar(3), dateDebut DATE) returns setof record
language plpgsql
as $$
 BEGIN 

/*DECLARE Performances TABLE(ID_CPA INT
                          , DT_CRS DATETIME
                          , PC_PRF FLOAT);*/

DECLARE Performances public.performancestb;

DECLARE NO_PTF INT
        ; DT_CRS DATE
        ; PC_PRF FLOAT
        ; ResultF FLOAT = 0
        ; PreviousResult FLOAT = 0
        ; PreviousCPA INT = 0;
        
/*DECLARE PerfCumul TABLE(NO_PTF INT
                        , DT_CRS DATE
                        , MT_PRF FLOAT);*/
                       
DECLARE PerfCumul public.perfcumultb;                       
            
--SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Chargement de l'historique des performances
--
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Performances (ID_CPA, DT_CRS, PC_PRF)
SELECT ID_CPA, DT_CRS, PC_PRF FROM public.UF_GetHistoriquePerformances(strDevise);
end;
--SELECT * FROM @Performances;

DECLARE curseur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT NO_PTF, DT_CRS, SUM(PC_PRF * MT_DEM) 
    FROM (
            SELECT D.NO_PTF, P.DT_CRS, P.PC_PRF
                 , D.MT_DEM/100 as MT_DEM
                FROM public.TB_Demande D
                    INNER JOIN
                    Performances      P ON D.ID_CPA =  P.ID_CPA
                                        AND D.MC_UTL =  strMatricule
            ) Q
    WHERE DT_CRS >= dateDebut
    GROUP BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS
    ORDER BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS;
begin
OPEN curseur;  

FETCH NEXT FROM curseur   
INTO NO_PTF, DT_CRS, PC_PRF;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declare` is a **block** not a prefix for each line. You only need to write it once and it has to go *before* the first `begin`

You cursor declaration is mixed with the actual code block.

So something like this:

```
DECLARE 
  Performances public.performancestb;
  NO_PTF INT; 
  DT_CRS DATE; 
  PC_PRF FLOAT; 
  ResultF FLOAT = 0; 
  PreviousResult FLOAT = 0; 
  PreviousCPA INT = 0;
  PerfCumul public.perfcumultb;                       
  
   curseur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT NO_PTF, DT_CRS, SUM(PC_PRF * MT_DEM) 
    FROM (
            SELECT D.NO_PTF, P.DT_CRS, P.PC_PRF
                 , D.MT_DEM/100 as MT_DEM
                FROM public.TB_Demande D
                    INNER JOIN
                    Performances      P ON D.ID_CPA =  P.ID_CPA
                                        AND D.MC_UTL =  strMatricule
            ) Q
    WHERE DT_CRS >= dateDebut
    GROUP BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS
    ORDER BY NO_PTF, DT_CRS;
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Performances (ID_CPA, DT_CRS, PC_PRF)
  SELECT ID_CPA, DT_CRS, PC_PRF 
  FROM public.UF_GetHistoriquePerformances(strDevise);

  OPEN curseur;  
  FETCH NEXT FROM curseur   
   INTO NO_PTF, DT_CRS, PC_PRF; 

  close curseur;
END;
```